# How to watch processor registers in kdevelop 4.x

Tags: cpu-registers, kdevelop4

I have been using KDevelop 4 for general C/C++ development for some time and I really like it. In order to develop for embedded systems though, I miss a processor registers and memory views, which I couldn't manage to find in the 4.x series yet. Does anyone know whether they are implemented in KDevelop and, if so, where they are? For now I can access processor registers by issuing a `info registers` command at KDevelop's GDB tab, but it would be really nice to have it properly integrated in the IDE instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not implemented. There is already a with in the bug database:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=273152

...feel free to contribute patches implementing this feature :D

Comment: They  implemented this feature in 2013. Great!